# Spark saveastextfile function is not working, showing an error instead

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to spark and am trying to see how each transformation works. In this example, I am trying to use the saveAsTextFile function in Spark but it seems to be showing

Below is my current code:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("hello")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
lines = sc.textFile("./exercise/hello.csv")

totalsByAge = rdd.mapValues(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]))
totalsByAge.saveAsTextFile(./mypath)
```

The error it shows is below:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_45824/1440435201.py in <module>
      6 
      7 rdd = lines.mapValues(lambda x: 1).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
----> 8 rdd.saveAsTextFile('./try')

~\bt4221_spark\spark\python\pyspark\rdd.py in saveAsTextFile(self, path, compressionCodecClass)
   1824             keyed._jrdd.map(self.ctx._jvm.BytesToString()).saveAsTextFile(path, compressionCodec)
   1825         else:
-> 1826             keyed._jrdd.map(self.ctx._jvm.BytesToString()).saveAsTextFile(path)
   1827 
   1828     # Pair functions

~\bt4221_spark\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

~\bt4221_spark\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o148.saveAsTextFile.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1090)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1088)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1061)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1026)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$3(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1008)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1007)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$2(PairRDDFunctions.scala:964)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:962)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$2(RDD.scala:1578)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1578)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1(RDD.scala:1564)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1564)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:551)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.saveAsTextFile$(JavaRDDLike.scala:550)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1868)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1910)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:678)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1868)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1910)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.getAllCommittedTaskPaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCommitter.commitJob(OutputCommitter.java:291)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:99)
    ... 50 more
```

Does anyone has any idea whats happening? It seems to be creating the empty folder but with no text file in it.

Found the issue:

The issue was that my Python, Java versions were outdated.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: Have you added MAVEN_HOME and updated path variable?

Comment: @DrashtiDobariya nope.. sorry what is that for?

Comment: @ernest_k added more info about the error:) thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 0):

`lines` defined above is already an rdd variable and you can perform dataset operations on it without referring to `rdd.mapValues`

```
totalsByAge = lines.mapValues(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]))
```

also, try passing the save path as a string

From documents, saveAsTextFile function is defined as:

```
 RDD.saveAsTextFile(path, compressionCodecClass=None)
```

Save this RDD as a text file, using string representations of elements.

```
Parameters

    path str: **path to text file**
    compressionCodecClass str, optional
```

Document Reference:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.saveAsTextFile.html

Comment: Can you replace rdd.mapValues() reference in your code to lines.mapValues().  I have Edited my answer as I noticed this now.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found the error. Its due to my Spark/Python/Java versions lol.. These version issues are really getting on my nerves.